# Describe the set of points for the given inequality. $x^2+y^2+z^2=36$, and $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 36$

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

To describe $x^2+y^2+z^2=36$, I know this is not a circle, so we can't say the origin is 36. Instead would it be correct to say, with what we know we can find the center and the radius of the sphere?

For $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 36$ I have the same idea, but I'm not sure what this means with the inequality.

Comment: The set $\{(x, y, z) \,|\, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36 \}$ is the same as the set of vectors $v$ in $\mathbb R^3$ whose square-magnitude $||v||^2 = 36,$ and this set can be identified with the sphere of radius 6 centered at the origin. One other way of seeing this is to convert to spherical coordinates $x = \rho \sin \varphi \cos \theta,$ $y = \rho \sin \varphi \sin \theta,$ and $z = \rho \cos \varphi,$ in which case we obtain $36 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \rho^2.$ Of course, in spherical coordinates, this is a sphere of radius 6 centered at the origin.

Comment: Using the previous comment, the set $\{(x, y, z) \,|\, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq 36\}$ can be naturally identified with the boundary of the sphere of radius 6 centered at the origin (i.e., $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36$) and everything outside of it (i.e., $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 36$).

Answer (score 0):

This just means $||(x,y,z)|| = 6$ and $||(x,y,z)||\geqslant 6$ so you are looking at the sphere of radius $6$ and its exterior in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Please, use precise terms. **Euclidean** sphere **centered in $0$** (the OP thinks it is "centered in $36$" (sic))  ; and the answer for the second question is **exterior to the corresponding ball** (not _sphere_ even if in common language we say sphere instead of ball)

Comment: I would agree I should have said euclidean, but I think you are just too precise while saying "exterior of corresponding ball" and not sphere. I mean, when you talk about Jordan's theorem, you say that a simple curve delimits two connected parts, the interior and the exterior. You are not saying "the exterior of the corresponding connected compact area whose boundary is the previous simple curve". I intended to talk about the exterior of the sphere, not of the ball. It makes sense.

Comment: I don't want to be a "Dutch uncle" ; I agree : "exterior" is not the most adapted term. Let us say that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 6^2$ is the **complementary set of the open ball** with center $0$ and radius $6$